# I exposed svelte to network but cannot seem to access from other device

Tags: networking, svelte, iot

```
  VITE v4.0.4  ready in 874 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:3333/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.xxx.1:3333/
  ➜  Network: http://172.22.xxx.1:3333/
  ➜  Network: http://10.0.0.xxx:3333/
  ➜  press h to show help
11:17:48 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] ssr compile done.
```

My end goal is to run some sort of application on my laptop and see if I can access that application from other devices.

So I ran svelte exposed to the network. However, I cannot seem to access that network URI using other devices which were my goal.

I am currently on Windows and I also disabled some of the firewall settings for port 3333.

I tried adding this rule to the firewall.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question but I've used the following solutions to solve a Network exposure problem.

1. Turn off VPN
2. Turn my network into Public - Go to Settings > Network & Internet > Your current Connection's Properties (*for me it's Ethernet 5*)  > Switch to `Public`
3. Run ipconfig in command prompt and use the IPv4 Address + ":PORT" as a URL.

*Make sure the device you're testing with is connected to the same network as you development computer

Happy coding..